# What is "sales" called in French?

Tags: traduction

We are trying to make a new e-mail account that people can reach us at for sales. What would you call that? **vente**@emaildomain.com ?

We have really tried to figure out what this is called on other sites, without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Vente* is fine as long as you use the plural:

- vente**s**@domaine.com

Other choices might be:

- service-clients@domaine.com
- service-commercial@domaine.com

Comment: I think the first one is good.

Comment: service-client@..., sans "s", cumule le sens de service-clientèle (sans l'accent, interdit ici), tout en donnant à chaque client le sentiment d'être unique, au lieu d'un client parmi tous les autres. C'est plus gratifiant, pour le client. En tant que client, c'est ainsi que je ressens la chose, et je suis un client difficile.

Comment: thank you so much <3

Comment: D'autre part, vous devez être cohérent avec la langue du domaine : sales@maboutique.fr est à éviter tout autant que service-client@something.co.uk :^)